# Custom Menu Loads page content from another file - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

So what I am trying to do here is:

Title0
--Subtitle1 - Hidden - onClick toggle()
--Subtitle2 - Hidden - onClick toggle()

When the user clicks "Title0", Subtitle1, Subtitle2 show on the left hand side and the page loads the content from another file. When that other file loads "Title0" along with "Subtitle1" and "Subtitle2" show be showing and depending on the links they click it should load that file and not collapse the menu.

so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: not sure I follow here... Do you mean you want to create a menu that has a different style/view for the active item?

Comment: no I have a menu that has items and subitems, using jquery when you click on the items it shows the subitems below the items, now what im trying to do is that when someone clicks on the item it loads content from another file as well as showing the subitems for that particular item.

Comment: well without any example code it is kind of difficult to know how to help, but give me a few minutes and I'll come up with an example (if no one beats me to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Menu HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu_item">Title0
    <ul style="display:none;">
      <li class="menu_subitem">Subtitle1</li>
      <li class="menu_subitem">Subtitle2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_item">Title1
    <ul style="display:none;">
      <li class="menu_subitem">Subtitle1</li>
      <li class="menu_subitem">Subtitle2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example of DIV to place the content you will load from another source:

```
<div id="load_stuff"></div>
```

Example JavaScript (assuming you already have the jQuery library included):

```
// process when doc is ready
$(function(){
    // add click event to LI elements with a "menu_item" class.
    $('li.menu_item').click(function(){

        // toggle the child element (subitems)
        $(this).children('ul').toggle();

        // load the page into the div with an id of "load_stuff"
        $('#load_stuff').load('http://mydomain.com/mypage.php');
    });
});
```

You're on your own for the menu formatting though.